# Layer selection changed connect signal none type issue

Tags: qgis, python, pyqgis

How propery use the layer selection changed method?
I am using following method. It shows error

> "NoneType" object is not callable

```
def test(): 
    print "selection changed"
```

layer.selectionChanged.connect(test)

Comment: Hard to answer if you show so little of your code ! How did u define your **layer** variable ? + i think the connection between **signal** (_selectionChanged_) and **slot** (_the test function_) must be elsewhere (i mean not in the body of the function called when signal is triggered) ...

Comment: Could you show the full error message? Another thing: Just like @snaileater said, you have to set the connection between the *signal* and *slot* in another method. Normally you would do this in your constructor. That would be the `__init__` method of your class.